# C++ Use of deleted function when defining or declaring class destructor

Tags: c++, list, c++11, components, entity

Im trying to make a really basic component entity system and I have been sucessfull so far. I can already add components of any type to a Entity. However I am struggling to implement any sort of destructor for my node-list object (double linked list for easy removal of components).

Essentially in my system a seperate object holds a unordered_map (std implementation) which takes a boost::uuid as a key and holds a list of type T (template). This acts like a unordered_multimap but with easier recursive acess etc. (I personally dont like the iterator implementation since I cant get it to work without entities leaking into other entities but thats just me).

Anyways the class im trying to make a destructor for is the list template class. Here is its full definition:

```
#ifndef LIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LIST_H_INCLUDED
#include "node.h"

template<class t>
class List:InstanceCounted<List<t>>
{
private:
    typedef Node<t> NodeT;
    std::unique_ptr<NodeT> head;
    void initHead(const t &data)
    {
        this->head=std::make_unique<NodeT>(data);
        this->head->setNext(nullptr);
        this->head->setPrev(nullptr);
    }
public:
    List()
    {}
    List(const t &data)
    {
        this->initHead(data);
    }
    NodeT* getHead()
    {
        return &*this->head;
    }
    void addNew(const t &data)
    {
        NodeT *last;
        try
        {
            last = &*this->head;
            while(last&&last->getNext())
            {
                last=last->getNext();
            }
            last->setNext(new NodeT(data));
            last->getNext()->setPrev(last);
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            if(!this->head)
            {
                this->initHead(data);
            }
        }
    }
    void removeFrom(const int id)
    {
        NodeT *last = &*this->head;
        register int i = 0;
        while(last&&last->getNext()&&i < id)
        {
            last=last->getNext();
            i++;
        }
        if(last==&*this->head)
        {
            this->head.reset(this->head->getNext());
        }
        else delete last;
    }

    void printListContents(){
        Node<t> *h = &*this->head;
        std::cout<<"---List<"<<typeid(t).name()<<"> start---"<<"\n";
        while(h){
            h->printNode();
            h=h->getNext();
        }
        std::cout<<"---List end---"<<"\n";
    }

    ~List(); //It doesnt matter if I define or declare this directly it 
             //always throws the same errors (+/- appropriate not found 
             //errors because of the missing code)
};

#endif // LIST_H_INCLUDED
```

Here are the errors:

```
(omitted)\compiler\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h|113|error: use of deleted function 'List<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::List(const List<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)'|

(omitted)\entitysystem\list.h|6|note: 'List<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::List(const List<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:|

(omitted)\entitysystem\list.h|6|error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Dp = std::default_delete<Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]'|

(omitted)\bits\unique_ptr.h|356|note: declared here|
```

Now I understand that this:

```
(omitted)\entitysystem\list.h|6|note: 'List<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::List(const List<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:|
```

is probably the key to the problem, however I dont understand

1. What it has to do with the destructor (I thought something like that
   would happen if you did something that implies that you wanna use
   the new standard like implementing a move contructor?)
2. Why it would require that constructor specifically?
3. How I can fix it?

I have uploaded my entire project to hastebin temporarily so you can play around with it a bit. I feel like this problem is nested within the system so I dont know how much I can omit from the project. If you need something smaller please ask. I did exclude the "instanceCounted.h" from the project because all it is is a template class that counts instances. If you need it I can add it though

Anyways I hope you can help me.

Here is the project: https://hastebin.com/ayiquxepic.cpp

Please also give feedback since I want to improve my style.

Comment: You can't copy a `std::unique_ptr`. That would undermine it's whole semantics. Thus your class design is wrong.

Comment: Im trying to declare a destructor man. It works as soon as I remove any sign of the destructor. How is it related to the destructor. Id get your point if I was doing a copy constructor

Comment: If you did everything right, you shouldn't need to declare one.

Comment: What why. Im making a class that holds a c style list. Its literally all raw pointers. I need a destructor. Also I asked why I wasnt allowed to make one not why its wrong to make one

Comment: You can apply alternate deleter functions with `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Why do you expect people to read though a ***full dump*** of your code when >90% of it is irrelevant? Delete the code that's irrelevant and not required to reproduce your problem. Verify you ***can*** still repro and repeat.... Keep deleting until you have the ***minimal*** amount of ***complete*** code that reproduces your problem. Often you'll figure your own problem out immediately. If not, you can at least ask a question that doesn't show disrespect to those you're asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to cppreference:

> Implicitly-declared move constructor
>
> If no user-defined move constructors are provided for a class type
>   (struct, class, or union), and all of the following is true:
>
> - there are no user-declared copy constructors;
> - there are no user-declared copy assignment operators;
> - there are no user-declared move assignment operators;
> - there are no user-declared destructors;
>
> then the compiler will declare a move constructor as a non-explicit inline public member of its class with the signature T::T(T&&).

Once you define a destructor, you must also define a move constructor in order for it to be used instead of the copy constructor.

When you instantiate an std::pair in the addList function of ComponentTable, the move constructor is used to insert it into the std::unordered_map. Defining the destructor means the move constructor is no longer implicitly declared, so the compiler attempts to use the copy constructor, which has been deleted.